# positioning several background layers

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a div container that takes up 100% of the width of the browser window. The height of the container changes with the window width. I want to use two images as background images. Horizontally: The first image should occupy the left half of the background, and the second image should occupy the right half.

In the vertical, the left picture should take up 90% of the height of the wrapper and the right picture only 70% of the height of the wrapper. The fact that the images will be distorted is not a problem, they are simple .jpgs that only have one colour.

In other words: The first layer starts in the top left corner, goes (horizontally) to the middle and takes vertically 90% of the space. The second layer starts (horizontally) in the middle, goes until the top right corner and takes (vertical) 70% of the space.

The code that I have now doesn't work, but I don't know if I can achieve what I want with CSS.

```css
#wrapper {
  background-image: url(/img1.jpg), url(img2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat; 
  background-position: 0 0, 50% 0;
  background-size: 50% 90%, 50% 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">...here my content</div>
```

Is it possible to do that? And if yes: How I can do it?

Comment: Please edit your post to include two suitable background images that are accessible to us here; without actual images we can't reproduce the issue (see [MCVE] for more info). You can use placeholder image websites for this or upload your real background images using the post editor and pasting the URLs that are created into the background image property value in the runnable Stack Snippet I added to your post.

Comment: At first glance this should work. Are you sure that the images are being loaded correctly? Also, is there a reason for using image files for the single colors rather than linear-gradients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background image set at 50% will be centered (so part of it is hidden under the first background image).

This snippet positions the second background image to the right and the first to the left.

[This snippet uses linear-gradients as images just to prove that it works OK].

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, red), linear-gradient(blue, blue);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: left top, right top;
  background-size: 50% 70%, 50% 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  /* added so we can see some height */
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">...here my content</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a better way to use colors instead of mages. 

About image just one more question: Is it possible to distort background images or do they always keep the same ratio? I am now just curious, cause I thought, that by defining the background-size (and not using "auto" for either length or height) we will create a (possibly) distorted image in the background.

Comment: Yes you can have a distorted background image.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img id="img1" src="img1.jpg">
      <img id="img2" src="img2.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
* {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: black;
}
#img1 {
  height: 90%;
}
#img2 {
  height: 70%;
}
```

This should do the trick :)

Comment: This answer could use some clarification or an example.

Comment: This doesn't really create the images as backgrounds.

Comment: @AHaworth I know, but it's more or less the same with divs and a background image.

Comment: How would the content of wrapper be dealt with?

Comment: What do you mean by "dealt with"?